# MySQL ORDER BY multiple columns from same multiple tables

Tags: mysql

So my problem is I'm trying to use ORDER BY on columns from multiple tables, the multiple tables are always the same one.

My SQL statement:

```
SELECT
n0.val AS n312, 
n1.val AS n309, 
c.food_name, 
f.name, 
FROM contents n0, contents n1, contents c
LEFT JOIN foods f ON f.id = c.food_id     
WHERE n0.url = c.url AND n0.orig_source_id = 312 AND n1.url = c.url AND n1.orig_source_id = 309
GROUP BY c.food_name
ORDER BY n312 DESC, n309 DESC
LIMIT 30
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Av8zOxp.png]

The problem is here only the n312 is ordered and not the n309, they both should be ordered right? I assume this is a problem with the multiple tables in the query but not sure how I can fix this. The values are both decimals.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected. `ORDER BY` is first ordering your table with column `n312` and then with column `n309`. Suppose you have a table like below:

```
 n312 | n309
-----------
 2.0 | 1.0
 5.0 | 2.0
 2.0 | 3.0
 3.0 | 2.0
 5.0 | 1.0
```

Then, The "ORDER BY" will arrange your table like below:

```
n312 | n309
-----------
 5.0 | 2.0
 5.0 | 1.0
 3.0 | 2.0
 2.0 | 3.0
 2.0 | 1.0
```

It first orders your rows by `n312`. If for two rows `n312` have the same value (e.g., row 1 and row 2), then it will order them with the value of column `n309`.

If you want something like:

```
n312 | n309
-----------
 5.0 | 3.0
 5.0 | 2.0
 3.0 | 2.0
 2.0 | 1.0
 2.0 | 1.0
```

Then you have to something similar like below:

```
 SELECT t1.n312, t2.n309 from 
   (select row_number() as id, n312 from t ORDER BY n312) as t1 
   JOIN 
   (select row_number() as id, n309 from t ORDER BY n309) as t2 
   WHERE t1.id = t2.id;
```

Idea is to order the table individually with both of the columns first and then select the ordered columns.

Comment: Hmm.. so how would I order by both of the columns? For example order by the highest of both of the columns first instead of just the one column, is it not possible?

Comment: I updated my answer. The query might not be the exact one but something similar will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think that should work...

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT n0.val AS n312, n1.val AS n309, c.food_name, f.name, 
FROM contents n0, contents n1, contents c
    LEFT JOIN foods f 
        ON f.id = c.food_id     
WHERE n0.url = c.url 
AND n0.orig_source_id = 312 
AND n1.url = c.url 
AND n1.orig_source_id = 309
GROUP BY c.food_name
ORDER BY n312 DESC, n309 DESC
LIMIT 30
) ORDER BY n312 DESC, n309 DESC
```

Comment: Nope, the same result, it's strange and I can't figure out what's wrong...